# C++ Armadillo: nearest neighbour

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm using C++ with the Armadillo library.

Suppose I have a n x 1 column matrix which is sorted in numerical order. For example

```
mat X; X.randn(100,1);
mat X_sorted; X_sorted = sort(X);
cout << X_sorted << endl;
```

and suppose I have a variable

```
double y = 0.5;
```

**What I want:** is a way of finding the index, `z`, of `x_sorted`, for which `x_sorted(z)` is **closest** to y. In the case of a tie (which doesn't actually matter in my case), simply choose the larger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is like this:

```
int z = as_scalar(sort_index(abs(X_sorted - y)).row(0));
```

Please feel free to criticise this solution and suggest an improvement.

Here's an example program of it in action:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

mat X; X.randn(100,1);
mat X2; X2.zeros(100,1);
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){X2(i) = i;}
mat X_sorted; X_sorted = sort(X);

mat XX; XX=join_rows(X2,X_sorted);
cout << XX << endl;

double y = 0.5;
int z = as_scalar(sort_index(abs(X_sorted - y)).row(0));
mat XX_z; XX_z = XX.row(z);
cout << XX_z << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution has the elegance of being in a single line. It does however not have the best possible asymptotic time complexity. Comparing every value to in the array to your variable has asymptotic time complexity `O(n)`. A binary search would have asymptotic time complexity `O(log(n))`.